# why the inconsistency performance in these two expressions?

Tags: javascript, coercion

```
''.valueOf()// an empty string
false.valueOf()// false
```

but why

```
+'' // 0
+false // 0
```

I read the tutorial, the algorithm of numeric conversion is:

If `valueOf` method exists and returns a primitive, then return it.

Otherwise, if `toString` method exists and returns a primitive, then return it.

Otherwise, throw an exception.

This is conflict with the real case, if that is the rule, then I think both `''.valueOf()` and `false.valueOf()` should return 0. Could anyone please let me know the possible reason?

Comment: See http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.6, "1. Let expr be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression. 2. Return [ToNumber](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3)([GetValue](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1)(expr))."

Comment: Run this to see the difference: `typeof('');` vs `typeof(+'');`. It's the difference between a `string` and a `number`

Comment: @Scimonster, the tutorial is http://javascript.info/tutorial/object-conversion

Comment: I don't understand why you think that getting different results when performing different operations is an inconsistency.

Answer (score 7):

From the [`Object.prototype.valueOf()` MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf):

> The valueOf() method returns the primitive value of the specified object.

Since you're calling `valueOf()` on primitives, it simply returns those primitives.

<sub>(In JavaScript, there are 6 [primitive data types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive): `String`, `Number`, `Boolean`, `Null`, `undefined`, `Symbol` (ES6))</sub>

---

Now, from the [`Unary Plus (+)` MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_(.2B)):

> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but attempts to converts it into a number, if it isn't already.

Basically, `+value` is equivalent to calling `Number(value)`.
Both `Number('')` and `Number(false)` return `0`.

Comment: @Bean: Does this clarify what's going on, to you?

Answer (score 4):

`.valueOf` is returning a primitive - the empty string. `false` is also a primitive.

The `+` operator is shorthand for converting a variable to a number. In this case, it is converting the false-y values to 0 - no conflict at all.